# Javascript extend class with props?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, oop

I have class defined as:

```
function MyClass() {

}

MyClass.prototype = {
       init: function() {
                 alert('My parent class!');
       },
       method1: function() {},
       method2: function() {}
};
```

and properties object:

```
{
     init: function() {
               MySubClass.superclass.init.apply(this, arguments);
               alert('test!');
     },

     test: function() {
               alert();
     }
}
```

and i need function which will be extends base class (MyClass) with props (object) and return NEW extended subclass (to MySubClass):

```
MySubclass = extend(MyClass, {
     init: function() {
               MySubClass.superclass.init.apply(this, arguments);
               alert('test!');
     },

     test: function() {
               alert();
     }
});
```

Constructor must be replaced by new constructor (from init).

I need a correct way.

Why it's not working good?

```
extend: function(bc, o) {
        // result class (apply only first constructor)
        var cls = function() {};
        cls.prototype = bc.prototype;

        for (var k in o)
            cls.prototype[k] = o[k];

        cls.superclass = bc.prototype;

        return cls;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `extend` function would have to look something like this - now this is much simpler than how you should really implement it but it should work:

```
var extend = function(Super, props) {
   var sinstance = new Super()
   var sclass = props.constructor || sinstance.constructor;
   sclass.prototype.super = sinstance;
   sclass.prototype.constructor = Super;

   //use underscore extend prototypes cause im too lazy to type it out
   _.extend(sclass.prototype, sinstance, props);
   return sclass;
}
```

Calling `subclass.super.call(this, props...)` allows you access overridden super methods.

Just tested and this works if underscore js is on the page:

```
function MyClass() {

}
MyClass.prototype = {
       init: function() {
                 alert('My parent class!');
       },
       method1: function() {},
       method2: function() {}
};

MySubclass = extend(MyClass, {
     init: function() {
               this.super.init.apply(this, arguments);
               alert('test!');
     },

     test: function() {
               alert();
     }
});

var test = new MySubclass();
test.init("yo"); //alerts My parent class
```

For your update you can also do this:

```
MySubclass2 = extend(MyClass, {
     constructor: function() {
        this.init();
     },

     init: function() {
               this.super.init.apply(this, arguments);
               alert('test!');
     },

     test: function() {
               alert();
     }
});

var test2 = new MySubclass2();//alerts My parent class
```

Comment: I think $.extend may also work but I dont recall the syntax for the method

Comment: `new Super()` will call  constructor of base class but i need replace class constructor by child class method.

Comment: Alright from your examples I assumed you wanted to use the `super` constructor. You'll need to pass the extend function a function like the version I just updated my answer with

Comment: You want to replace the constructor? As in `MyClass = otherCtor`?

Comment: I just want replace all from props object include constructor in function.

Comment: Call the original function with `{constructor: function() {}}` as props then

Comment: @megawac, it's not working. after calling superclass constructor i have error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a library, use _.extend from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/). Otherwise, add this code to your codebase:

```
extend = function(obj) {
    each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
      if (source) {
        for (var prop in source) {
          obj[prop] = source[prop];
        }
      }
    });
    return obj;
  };
```

Comment: it's object-orient programming and MyClass isn't object. MyClass is function which i want extend with object.

Comment: @xercool `MyClass` is actually an object, although it's a `Function` object. Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

I see you've tagged with jQuery - if you are indeed using jQuery, you may be interested in using [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Comment: Thank @ Max i am glad some sane! $.extend is my most used jquerie plug in all the time I use it for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/haroldiedema/joii

```
var BaseClass = function() 
{
    this.some_var = "foobar";

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    this.someMethod = function() {
        return this.some_var;
    }
};

var MyClass = new Class({ extends: BaseClass }, function()
{
    /**
     * @param string value
     */
    this.__construct = function(value)
    {
        this.some_var = value;
    }

})
```

Usage:

```
var obj = new MyClass("Hello World!");
console.log( obj.someMethod() ); // Hello World!
```